# How can I implement this environment? (Title - Margin - Item)

Tags: environments

[image: This is made by MS-Word]

I want to make this environment or macro in LaTeX.

This picture is made by ms-word.

Suppose that 'Title' and 'How' is 3cm of width and there is a 1cm margin between 'Title' and 'Title 1'. and other space is for the content (Title 1, Title 2, How can I implement this?, etc...). Of course, 'Title' and 'How' should span whole 3cm widely.

I want to make a environment or macro like:

```
\begin{somethingiwant}{Title}
  \item Title 1
  \item Title 2
\end{somethingiwant}

\begin{somethingiwant}{How}
  \item How can I implement this?
  \item Etc...
\end{somethingiwant}
```

The gap, or line space, between 'Title 1' and 'Title 2' should be same with when I type:

```
Title 1 \\ Title 2
```

I don't know how to implement this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything that's possible with word processing programs is necessarily good typography. Here's a version with exaggerated letter spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{
  leftmargin=4cm,% adjust to suit
  labelwidth=4cm,% the same as leftmargin
  labelsep=0pt,
  before=\let\makelabel\expandedlabel,
  label=\textbullet, 
  align=left,
}
\newcommand\expandedlabel[1]{%
  \makebox[3cm][s]{% adjust 3cm to suit
    \sffamily\bfseries\expanditem{#1}%
  }%
  \hfill
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\expanditem}[1]{%
  \hfilneg
  \@tfor\next:=#1\do{\hfil\next}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
\item[Title] title 1 \\ title 2
\item[How] How \\ How to
\end{mylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I use Korean which is possible with koTeX (I think you have not heard about this). When I use Korean letter, it gives an error message : ! Improper alphabetic constant. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I found that the problem is on `\expanditem`.

Comment: @Analysis Probably `\item[{T}{i}{t}{l}{e}]` will work. But I wouldn't expand the labels to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,showframe}      %% showframe only for demo
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{leftmargin=*}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mylist}[{label=\makebox[3cm][l]{\bfseries Title}}]
    \item title 1 \\ title 2
    \item Title
  \end{mylist}
  \begin{mylist}[label={\makebox[3cm][l]{\bfseries How}}]
    \item How \\ How to
    \item How do I?
  \end{mylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea of *@Harish Kumar* i tried to implement something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength{\fwidth} % Width of the `label column`
\setlength{\fwidth}{2.5cm} % Fix width of label
\newlist{mlist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mlist]{leftmargin=*,labelsep=0pt}

\newenvironment{mylist}[2][\fwidth]%
{\begin{mlist}[{label=\makebox[#1][l]{\bfseries #2}}]%
\item\begin{itemize}[label={},noitemsep]}%
{\end{itemize}\end{mlist}}


\begin{document}
\begin{mylist}{Title}
  \item Title 1
  \item Title 2
\end{mylist}
Change width by default to 3 cm
\begin{mylist}[3cm]{Title} % Change width by default to 3cm
  \item Title 1
  \item Title 2
\end{mylist}

\begin{mylist}{How}
  \item How can I implement this?
  \item Etc...
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

with a *environment* seemed to the desired by OP.

[image]